# In OS X how do I tell programmatically if the computer is connected to the internet?

Tags: networking

I'm brand new to network programming, so please forgive the question if it turns out to be ridiculously simple.

I want to write a program to track the uptime of my ISP. How do I check to see if the computer that the program is running on is currently connected?  Do I have to exchange traffic with a specific external server, or is there a way to query the system and say "Hey, you connected?"

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE` or `osx`?

Comment: This is a difficult problem at its core. Pinging, or retrieving webpages *might* work, but might not if user is behind a proxy, or there are switch/routers which drop ICMP (ping) packages. Most likely you need to allow the user to provide e.g. proxy information, or any relevant information. If it's just for you, then "whatever works" should be fine

Comment: This is a difficult problem at its code because 'connected to the Internet' isn't well-defined. 'Connected' itself isn't well-defined in TCP/IP.

Comment: It has to do with Xcode and OS X because that's the environment that I want to do it on, and there might have been the possibility that one of Apple's frameworks might contain a function or object that would simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

Ping another machine over the internet or try to fetch a webpage。

Comment: Be careful not to do it *too* often, though. Once every 5-10 minutes is probably fine (and even once per minute for a ping) but you don't want to be fetching the same webpage every second of every day, especially if you are on a data cap!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer